# Is the Transaction Hash from block frost the same as the transaction id?

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync, cardano-address, api, blockfrost

When making an API (HTTP) Get  request to the blockfrost API service, you can specify an address and get the transactions at the address  ([https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/~1addresses~1{address}~1txs/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/%7E1addresses%7E1%7Baddress%7D%7E1txs/get)).

Is the Hash it gives you the same as the ID of the transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `tx hash` and `tx id` are the same. The terminology is getting used interchangably.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer